# Was Valentino the first person to be called ‘sexy’?

Tags: word-usage, etymology, semantics

According [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/sexy) , the term *sexy* underwent a semantic change in the early 1920s when it was used to for the first time with the connotation of “sexually attractive” in reference to [Rudolph Valentino](https://simple.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rudolph_Valentino):

***Sexy:***

> 1905, from sex (n.) + -y (2). Originally "engrossed in sex;" ***sense of "sexually attractive" is 1923, first in reference to Valentino***. An earlier word in this sense was sexful (1898).

I couldn’t find any evidence of *sexy* used at that time referring to Valentino in [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sexy&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csexy%3B%2Cc0) or other online sources.

Questions:

- Was the term “sexy” meaning attractive really first used for Valentino in the early 1920s or was this usage already in place in before then?
- Is there evidence that “sexy” was used at that time to refer to the famous actor?

Answer (score 7):

Etymonline seems to be out of date here. The earliest examples in this sense are from before Valentino was even in a movie (at least according to the Wikipedia page linked in the question).

I found what looks to be a really early example from 1901:

> You should always take a windy day when you wish to study the Sex; because on a calm day the Sex is not, so to speak, anything like so sexy.
>   <sub>[The Clipper](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/83088065?searchTerm=sexy)</sub>

The Oxford English Dictionary gives an example from 1912:

> If a woman is genuinely keen to win the affections of a man she is a universal woman of the real sexy sort.
>   <sub>Colorado Springs Gazette</sub>

The OED also has an example from the 1923 LA Times referring to both men and women, but this doesn't seem to be the quote Etymonline is referring to either:

> Even Elinor Glyn, who rather specializes in sexy heroines, has obviously been confronted with this type... The sexiest men have quite a number of other and more important interests.

---

Also, Etymonline asserts that the first use of the word (in any sense) was first used in 1905, but the OED has an earlier quote from 1896 (albeit with a different spelling):

> Lane had decided..not to handle your work of genius, on the score that it was seksy & America didn't want no seks-problems.
>   <sub>[A. Bennett's *Letters*](https://books.google.com/books?id=CGpaAAAAMAAJ&q=%22on+the+score+that+it+was+seksy%22&dq=%22on+the+score+that+it+was+seksy%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizgZ6S99TeAhUmmeAKHWleAPAQ6AEIKjAA)</sub>

(Do note that "seksy" means "erotic" in the above quote as it is a different sense of the word.)

Comment: Yes. This was  my own take - having looked at the OED. The latter also seems to regard "sexful" (mentioned by the OP as an earlier term) as a synonym of "sexy", across roughly the same time span, with examples from 1894 to 1997. The OP's assertion about it first having been used for a male person, is rather contradicted by the OED, who - under sense 2a, says "esp of a woman".